# Code is valid in Eclipse, cannot be compiled by the JDK

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm experiencing an interesting discrepancy between what Eclipse and my JDK considers legal java.

Eclipse compiles the following class without a hitch, while the JDK on Mac OS X produces the error included below.

```
public class Builder {  
    private class Item {}

    public void addItem(Item i) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Builder() {{
            addItem(new Item());
        }};
    }
}
```

```
$ javac Builder.java 
Builder.java:9: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            addItem(new Item());
                    ^
1 error
```

Making the `Item` class static resolves the problem, but it left me a bit curious: Is Eclipse being lenient and compiling code that is not actually valid? Did I stumble upon an eccentricity of the Mac OS X JDK? Am I missing something?

**Update** 
Might be relevant to include the following

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
```

**Update 2**

Making the Item more visible (default, protected or public) also satisfies the JDK compiler.

Comment: and what happens when you launch it from eclipse?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using a different *compiler* like jikes?

Comment: @DilumRanatunga: Eclipse uses its own compiler, ECJ, and not javac

Comment: @EugenePavlovsky: Eclipse has no trouble running it. I'm tempted to break out a decompiler and compare class files.

Comment: it compiles with the 1.7 compiler, but not with the 1.6, must be some bug in the compiler they have fixed

Comment: Do you have Build Automatically on in Eclipse?  It probably needs to build and validate first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

javac 1.7.0_04 compiles the source without error, so I'd suggest this is a bug in javac 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same result, but interestingly, changing the code to:

```
new Builder() {{
    addItem(this.new Item());
}};
```

(which should be identical) produces a different error message:

```
Builder.java:9: Builder.Item has private access in Builder
            addItem(this.new Item());
```

I suspect this is the real underlying error - the `Item` class is private, so is not visible in the anonymous subclass.  Changing `Item` to be protected rather than private allows both the original version and the `this.new` version to compile successfully.

Comment: The private visibility of Item is also interesting. When using the addItem(new Item()) version of the code, eclipse explains why the item is visible from an anonymous Builder subclass: "Access to enclosing constructor Builder.Item() is emulated by a synthetic accessor method"

Comment: What happens with this if you change the private to protected?

Comment: @RichardSitze: it compiles without error, in both the original `new Item()` and my modified `this.new Item()` forms.

Comment: Extremely interesting! I've now found two ways to fix the code for JDK compilation: Make the Item class static OR change the visibility of Item to default.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>In Eclipse by default, `Access to a non-accessible member of an enclosing type` may be ignored by default. If you go Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Errors/Warning you can enable project specific settings.</strike>

The discrepancy is probably because Eclipse comes with its own compiler - part of [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php), which acts a bit different than `javac`.

Comment: You're right. When turning this on, eclipse gives me an error: "Access to enclosing constructor Builder.Item() is emulated by a synthetic accessor method".Very interesting

Comment: Are you sure that this is related? I set "Access to a non-acc[...]" to error. The result was that "new Item()" was marked as an error, but a quick-fix was made available which adds a no-parameters constructor to the Item class. Doing this satisfied Eclipse.

Comment: @Henrik agree, it is a bit off. In any case, looks like Eclipse compiler and javac behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in the eclipse compiler. The internal Item class is not static, so you can access it only through a Builder object, like this:

`new Builder().new Item()`

Initializing the Item class in a static block, you don't have an instance of Builder, so this code you posted shouldn't work.
Very interesting error.

Comment: But the code accessing the `Item` constructor is an initializer block of a subtype of `Builder`...

Answer (score -2):

Add static to the class declaration of item, like `static class Item {}`

Comment: "Making the Item class static resolves the problem, but it left me a bit curious: Is Ec"... They're wondering why, without the static modifier, it runs fine in Eclipse, but not directly off JDK. (Not how to make it work in both)

Comment: @Henrik already mentioned this. But the question remains -- does the code for an anonymous subtype's instance initializer block use the same name-scoping as a named subtype, or does it use the name-scoping of the defining code?

Comment: Bali's response isn't really "wrong", it's just sparse and focused on one aspect of the problem without discussing "why".

Comment: Sorry then, my bad, i didn't read the whole question, i tought, that you only want to make it work.